# How to passa data from the controller to the database for a list

Tags: php, database, symfony, object, doctrine

I made a web-application with symfony2, where a registrated user can query for a file and visualize it. I'm trying to pass the information from the controller to the template.

When I pass the information of a single object, it works properly. You can see the controller here:

```
 public function showAction($id)
 {
       $product = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Product')
       ->find($id);

       if (!$product) {
       throw $this->createNotFoundException(
           'Nessun prodotto trovato per l\'id '.$id
       );
       }       

       return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle::showdata.html.twig', array('Id'    => $product->getId(), 'Name' => $product->getName(), 'UploadTime'=> $product-  >getUploadTime()));
```

}

But what can I do if I want to display the whole list?
If I change the

```
       ->find($id);
```

with

```
       ->findAll();
```

of course I get error.

```
( Call to a member function getId() on a non-object).
```

How can I display the whole list?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `findAll` returns an array, you need to write a loop to process them.

Comment: Where I have to put the loop, into the render, right?

Comment: Around the render probably. Maybe Symphony has a pattern for automating it, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: make the loop in twig, and send the list to that twig file http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass all the products data to your twig view

```
public function showAction()
{
$products = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Product')
->findAll();

if (empty($products)) {
throw $this->createNotFoundException(
    'No products found'
);
}

return $this->render('AcmeGroundStationBundle::showdata.html.twig', 
array('products' => $products)); 
}
```

Then in your view you can list products with their information as

```
{% if products is defined and products is not empty %}

    {% for p in products %}

       id : {{  p.getId() }} <br>
       Name: {{  p.getName() }} <br>
       Upload Time: {{  p.getUploadTime() }} <br>

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

**EDIT**

`findAll()` will give all the results to get the latest 10 you need use `findBy`

```
findBy(
array(), // $where 
array('id' => 'DESC'), // $orderBy
10, // $limit
0 // $offset
);
```

Comment: If I want to show only 10 results I have to change my query form, isn't it? Or can I also do directly from the template? For example, showing the last 10 objects uploaded (so with the higher id).
I saw " ->setMaxResults($limit) ", can I use it in my controller?